# how can i select a value from a table and display it inside an alert box?

Tags: javascript, html

I want when clicking  Delete, the alert box will show me the name of user like this: are you sure you want to delete (selected_name)?

this is my table:

```
<?php 
    require '../db.php';

    $sql = "select * from users;";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>password</th>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<th><input class='img' type='image' name='Edit' src='Edit.png' alt='Edit' onclick='Edit()'></th>";
    echo "<th><input class='img' type='image' name='Delete' src='Delete.png' alt='Delete' onclick='Delete()'></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; 

    ?>
```

this is Delete functions:

```
function Delete() {
    alert("are you sure you want to Delete this user ?");
    window.location.href = "Delete.php";
}
```

Comment: Do you want it deleted only in the frontend or in database as well?

Comment: You can pass the name of the user as an argument to the Delete function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name into the `Delete` function:

```
 echo "<th><input class='img' type='image' name='Delete' src='Delete.png' alt='Delete' onclick='Delete(\"{$row["name"]}\")'></th>";
```

And in the `Delete` function:

```
function Delete(name) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete " + name + "?")){
      window.location.href = "Delete.php";
    }
}
```

You should also use `confirm` instead of `alert`, this gives the user the option to cancel.